# Re-ordering and sorting of Pandas DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to store values to the pandas dataframe and I am able to achieve that, but the problem is the data is being displayed horizontally. I want the data to be displayed vertically. You can see how the data is being currently displayed below.

[image]

I would also want the column names to be "cummulativeCall" instead of "unnamed 0" and "cummulativePut" instead of "unnamed 1" and "totalValue" instead of "unnamed 2". I also would have the dataframe sorted based on "totalValue"

The output I am expecting is

[image]

You can find the code below

```
      cum_call = []
      cum_put = []
      total_value = []
      strike_price = ce_data['strikePrice']
      cum_call = abs(closest_strike -  ce_data['strikePrice']) * (ce_data['openInterest'] * 50)
      cum_put = abs(closest_strike - pe_data['strikePrice']) * (pe_data['openInterest'] * 50)

      total_value = cum_call + cum_put

            #mp_result = pd.DataFrame([strike_price,cum_call, ce_data['askPrice'], cum_put, pe_data['askPrice'],total_value])
            mp_result = pd.DataFrame([strike_price, cum_call,  cum_put,  total_value])
)
print(mp_result)
```

I so far managed to have the data loaded into the frame, but I am not able to sort them and have it displayed as per my liking

Comment: Images of data are not accepted here, please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing a reproducible input.

That said, given the provided code, you're creating 4 lists and combine them directly with the DataFrame constructor, which gives this unwanted wide format.

Instead, use a dictionary in the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) constructor to create columns and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
mp_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'strike_price': strike_price,
    'cummulativeCall': cum_call,
    'cummulativePut': cum_put,
    'totalValue': total_value,
]).sort_values(by='totalValue')
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am getting a KeyError when I try it .  " k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by[0], axis=axis),raise KeyError(key),KeyError: 'total_value'"

Comment: @Satheesh oops I didn't use the same name, see update.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sections of this. To rotate your dataframe on its axis, try dataframe.transpose()

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

```
mp_result.transpose()
```

will give you (my numbers might be slightly different than yours)

```
0   1       2       3           4
0   3420.0  0.0     74250.0     0.0
1   3440.0  26100.0 913500.0    26100.0
2   3450.0  15500.0 3596000.0   15500.0
3   3460.0  22000.0 4500000.0   22000.0
```

Than you can rename the columns with dataframe.rename()

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

I'm showing it here chained onto the transpose call as

```
mp_result.transpose().rename(columns={0: "strikePrice", 1: "cumulativeCall", 2: "cumulativePut", 3:"totalValue"})
```

This will give you

```
    strikePrice cumulativeCall  cumulativePut   totalValue
0   3420.0      0.0             74250.0         0.0
1   3440.0      26100.0         913500.0        26100.0
2   3450.0      15500.0         3596000.0       15500.0
3   3460.0      22000.0         4500000.0       22000.0
```